# Are there any reliable optical measurements of the radius of a neutron star?

Tags: observational-astronomy, neutron-star

I know that there is plenty of theory to predict the size of a neutron star:  my question is whether or not there are any reliable size estimates based on observation. Please note that, to be reliable, such an observation would need to have also a good estimate for the neutron star's distance from us, which must necessarily be reckoned from some independent source, i.e., it must *not* be reckoned from the apparent size of the object, or from theory, otherwise one is guilty of circular reasoning!

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265006/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Not an exact duplicate as currently worded. This focuses on measuring the radius, whereas the one on Physics has been constrained to mere observation.

Comment: @called2voyage: The Phys.SE question has been edited (see v4).

Comment: @Qmechanic It has been rolled back to the original state which is different than this question.

Comment: @Qmechanic Plus: This discussion is now in a chat-room, titled "Discussion on question by PERFESSER CREEK-WATER"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the neutron star [RX J1856.5-3754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RX_J1856.5-3754) has an observed* radius of 17 km. After accounting for general relativity, its actual radius is calculated as 14 km. It is not the only [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Neutron_stars) whose radius is known.

---

* It's worth mentioning how astronomers arrived at this radius. Technically, fitting the X-ray data to a blackbody arrives at a calculation of a 5 km radius, which seems unusually small, so for a time it was believed that this star may be something more exotic, like a quark star. However, after atmospheric modeling based on temperature, a more accurate estimate of the emission radius was derived to be 17 km. Once gravitational redshift was accounted for, the value of 14 km was yielded. See [Magnetic Hydrogen Atmosphere Models and the Neutron Star RX J1856.5−3754 - Wynn C. G. Ho, et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0612145v1.pdf)

Comment: It might be worth including how this measurement was done: Not by direct imaging or course, but by considering the temperature and the brightness.

Comment: @JamesKilfiger Added. This is not my subject area--I'm just reading the paper, so let me know if I have introduced any inaccuracies.

Comment: @JamesKilfiger  I, too, must admit that much of the paper is "over my head" ... however, I get the idea that they made a lot of assumptions, re the composition of the objects atmosphere, magnetic-field strength, etc., with the goal of explaining away the initial finding of a 5km radius ----- which they characterized as "rather small for a neutron star" ... it's well-known that scientists have a TENDENCY to do this, so that their results fit the "accepted" numeric-values .....

Comment: @PERFESSERCREEK-WATER On the contrary, I find that there were more assumptions made for the 5km figure.

Comment: @called2voyage Well, I can't argue with you there, as I don't know enough about the details of either of the findings.